# perl script sendMail

Tags: perl

I need to write a perl script for sending emails. 
The script should read .txt document containing the e-mail addresses as its first argument (there could be more than one address, and they are all separated with ";")  and an .html document that should be the body of the e-mail as its second.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Net::SMTP::SSL;

sub send_mail {

    my $to = $ARGV[0];
    open(MYFILE, $to) || die("Could not open file!");
    @recepients=<MYFILE>;
    close(MYFILE);

    my $body = $ARGV[1];
    open (TXTFILE, $body);
    @lines = <TXTFILE>;
    close(TXTFILE);
    $body = join("",@lines);

    my $from = 'theAddress@gmail.com';
    my $password = 'thePassword';

    my $smtp;

    if (not $smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new('smtp.gmail.com',
                            Port => 465,
                            Debug => 1)) {
        die "Could not connect to server\n";
    }

    $smtp->auth($from, $password) || die "Authentication failed!\n";

    $smtp->mail($from . "\n");

    my @recepients = split(/;/, $to);
    foreach my $recp (@recepients) {
        $smtp->to($recp . "\n");
    }
    $smtp->data();
    $smtp->datasend("From: " . $from . "\n");
    $smtp->datasend("To: " . $to . "\n");
    $smtp->datasend("Subject: " . $subject . "\n");
    $smtp->datasend("\n");
    $smtp->datasend($body . "\n");
    $smtp->dataend();
    $smtp->quit;
}

&send_mail()
```

So I tried to work something out, but I have a problem with extracting the information both from the .txt and .html documents. So the error should be somewhere at the splitting of the recipients.

Comment: Check your `$to` variable. It's a filename, not the first line of the file... Also, some pointers to improvement: `use strict`, `open(my $fh, '<', 'filename')` and `File::Slurp`.

Comment: yeah, i fixed that, and now it does work, but if i leave only one e-mail address in the .txt, otherwise it still doesn`t sepparates them. If you could only help me with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several issues in your script. I would suggest you to use [Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/~elliotjs/Perl-Critic-1.116/lib/Perl/Critic.pm) as it analyzes your code and usually gives helpful hints.

The following works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Always use `strict` and `warnings`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SMTP::SSL;
```

`English` will give a textual representation of error messages

```
use English qw(-no_match_vars);
```

`Carp` issues warnings and error from the perspective of the caller

```
use Carp;

our $VERSION = '1.0.0';

sub send_mail {

    my ( $to, $body ) = @_;
```

it is better to have filehandles as variables too

```
    my $to_handle;
    my $text_handle;
```

Always declare variables

```
    my @recipients;
    my @lines;
```

Always check the return value of system calls (open, close, ...)

```
    # print the error message in case of errors
    open $to_handle, '<', $to
      or croak "Error opening $to: $OS_ERROR";
    @recipients = <$to_handle>;
    close $to_handle
      or croak "Error closing $to: $OS_ERROR";

    open $text_handle, '<', $body
      or croak "Error opening $body: $OS_ERROR";
    @lines = <$text_handle>;
    close $text_handle
      or croak "Error closing $body: $OS_ERROR";

    $body = join '', @lines;

    my $from     = '.....@gmail.com';
```

I would avoid putting a password in the script source

```
    my $password = '*****';

    my $smtp;
```

Don't put a new line at the end of die/warn/... as it will remove the line number where the error occurred

```
    $smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new(
        'smtp.gmail.com',
        Port  => 465,
        Debug => 1
    ) or croak 'Could not connect to server';

    $smtp->auth( $from, $password )
      or croak 'Authentication failed!';

    $smtp->mail( $from . "\n" );

    # removed trailing \n
    chomp $recipients[0];
```

The `;` separated list is in the first line (the first element of your array): you have to split the first line.

```
    foreach my $recp ( split /;/mxs, $recipients[0] ) {
        $smtp->to( $recp . "\n" );
    }

    $smtp->data();
    $smtp->datasend( "From: $from\n" );
    $smtp->datasend( "To: $to\n" );
```

`$subject` was not defined, you would have detected it with `strict` and `warnings`

```
    $smtp->datasend("Subject: Test\n");
    $smtp->datasend("\n");
    $smtp->datasend("$body\n" );
    $smtp->dataend();
    $smtp->quit;
```

It is a good practice to end subroutines with a return as perl uses the result of the last evaluation as a result if return is not specified.

```
    return;

}
```

Evaluate `ARGV` in the main body. You will loose clarity if you scatter the processing in one or several subroutines

```
if ( !$ARGV[0] || !$ARGV[1] ) {
    print STDERR "usage: send to content\n";
    exit 1;
}
```

There was a missing semicolon. You don't need to use & to call subroutines

send_mail( $ARGV[0], $ARGV[1](http://search.cpan.org/~elliotjs/Perl-Critic-1.116/lib/Perl/Critic.pm) );

```
1;
```